# Show some text on content div(image)

Tags: css, html

I have created three div

```
Header  
content  
Footer
```

Now I need to show some text on content div(image)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J9bjm/507/)

I tried to use left/ top, but it always fail if laptop screen size changes.

Comment: Need to clarify the question. I'm not sure what you're trying to do yet.

Comment: I need to add " i am here to help you" a normal text in left side of image, but this text always changes.

Comment: Which "image" are you referring to? And is this something you need to do dynamically (i.e. through script)?

Comment: Why are you posting the same fiddle link twice, what difference do you want to see??

Comment: the image you are trying to load in `background-image:...` is not working. I mean I can't load it. Are you sure you have working link and not 404 error ?

Comment: yes .. its loading fine in chrome... this is full screen results http://jsfiddle.net/J9bjm/507/embedded/result/

Comment: @Kasma when I am trying to open your link in the chrome I am just getting a page with header and background-color:#EEE ie(black background) nothing else there is no image in the body..

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the your image url problem. I have used another image, check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/J9bjm/514/

Answer (score 0):

yes, i think sowmya is right there is a problem in the image url.
i also tried it check this http://jsfiddle.net/zajy4/